# Extension of smooth functions

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, smooth-functions

Let $\mathbb H^n=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:x_n\geq 0\}$. I saw the following definition:

1. A function $f:U\to\mathbb R$ defined on an open subset of $\mathbb H^n$ is smooth iff it has a smooth extension to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

However in the halfspace $\mathbb H^n$ the notion of partial derivatives still makes sense so for example even if  for $y\in U$ we have $y_n=0$ we could  define  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(y)=\lim_{h\to0,\,h\geq 0}\frac{f(y+h\cdot e_n)-f(y)}{h}$$

if the right hand side exists. Clearly if $f$ is smooth as in 1. all partial derivatives exist.

The question is: If all partial derivatives of all order exist, is $f$ smooth as in 1.?

Comment: Since these things are known (while I am not a specialist), I could sketch a proof of "YES" but since these things are known, I wouldn't take time to fill in the details.

Comment: Since these things are not known to me i would appreciate a sketch or a pointer to the literature.

Comment: References: 1. John Milnor, Morse Theory; 2. Manfredo Perdigao do Carmo, Riemannian Geometry. There is also a classic (0) Sigurdur Helgason, Differential Geometry, Lie Groups and Symmetric Spaces. *** The last but not least, Michael Spivak, Calculus on manifolds.(pdf on-line). All of these texts are great!

Comment: Thanks. I looked for it in Spivak (1995 Edition), do Carmo (1991 English Edition) and Milnor but unfortunately could not find it. In what chapter/ on what page is it?

Comment: This short paper of Seeley might be of interest: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1964-015-04/S0002-9939-1964-0165392-8/S0002-9939-1964-0165392-8.pdf